# Determinant of Matrix $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Consider the matrix
>        $$S=\begin{pmatrix}
> s & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0&a_{1}\\
>   -1 & s & 0 & \cdots &0& a_2\\
>   0 & 0 & s & \cdots &0& a_{3}\\
> \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots&\vdots\\ 
>   0 &0&\ddots&-1&s&a_{n-1}\\    
> 0 & 0 & \cdots &0& -1& s + a_n
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   where  $s,a_1,a_2, \dots a_n \in F$ such that $s \neq 0$.

How can I show
that $det(S) =s^{n} + a_ns^{n-1}+ \dots + a_2s +a_1$ ?

Comment: @One Above All: Can I miss something in the edit?  I don't know. If so, let me know or go ahead and edit again...!

Comment: @oneaboveall Please show us your attempts and thoughts on this question.

Comment: why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 4):

Prove by induction.

Base Case: Observe
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
s & a_1\\
-1 & s+a_2
\end{vmatrix} = s^2+a_2s+a_1.
\end{align}

Inductive Case: Suppose the statement holds for $n=k$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
s & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &  a_1\\
-1 & s & 0 & \cdots & 0& a_2\\
0 & -1 & s & \cdots & 0 & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots\\ 
\vdots & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & s & a_{k-1}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & s+a_k
\end{vmatrix} = s^k+a_k s^{k-1}+\cdots+ a_1
\end{align}
Then we see that
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
s & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &  a_1\\
-1 & s & 0 & \cdots & 0& a_2\\
0 & -1 & s & \cdots & 0 & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots\\ 
\vdots & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & s & a_{k}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & s+a_{k+1}
\end{vmatrix} =& s\begin{vmatrix}
s & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &  a_2\\
-1 & s & 0 & \cdots & 0& a_3\\
0 & -1 & s & \cdots & 0 & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots\\ 
\vdots & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & s & a_{k}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & s+a_{k+1}
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &  a_1\\
-1 & s & 0 & \cdots & 0& a_3\\
0 & -1 & s & \cdots & 0 & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots\\ 
\vdots & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & s & a_{k-1}\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & s+a_k
\end{vmatrix}\\
=&\ s\left(s^k+a_{k+1}s^{k-1}+\cdots+a_2 \right) +(-1)^{k-1} a_1 (-1)^{k-1}\\
=& s^{k+1}+a_{k+1}s^k + \ldots +a_2s+ a_1
\end{align}

Comment: My bad but i didn't get the logic of the last part can you explain why.